# Vue3 App Initialization chaining syntax with config.globalProperties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, eventemitter

I started a Vue3 project with Vue CLI. The app initialization code was:

```
createApp(App)
.use(AudioVisual)
.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
.mount('#app')
```

Now I want to use [mitt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt) to use event emitter, and thus I need to use *app.config.globalProperties*. So, I used the following syntax-

```
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(AudioVisual);
app.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon);
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter;
app.mount('#app');
```

Is there any way, I can use the first syntax and use *mitt* in my application? I tried

```
createApp(App)
    .config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter;
    ...
```

But that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter` is an expression and isn't supposed to be chained. It may be beneficial to preserve `app` reference any way for testing or else, so chaining isn't crucial for initialization.

The assignment of global instance property can be done as regular Vue plugin; this is what third-party plugins commonly do:

```
createApp(App)
.use({
  install(app) {
    app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter;
  }
})
...
.mount("#app");
```