# Laravel - Ziggy Err: $route is not a function

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs, ziggy

I try use stack Laravel + Inertiajs + Vue3. I would like to use the ziggy library to build routes.

And my **error** in browser console:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.$route is not a function`

- Laravel successful
- Inertiajs successful
- Vue3 successful

Next i install [Ziggy](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy#vue)

```
composer require tightenco/ziggy.
```

my **app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress'
import { ZiggyVue } from 'ziggy';

InertiaProgress.init()

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin, ZiggyVue)
            .mount(el)
    },
})

console.log(route('test'))
```

my **webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');


mix.alias({
    ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue'),
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);
```

my root **blade**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        <link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
        @routes
        <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body>
        @inertia
    </body>
</html>
```

my vue page **Pages/Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <Head title="Welcome" />
    <h1 class="text-9xl">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Hello, welcome to your first Inertia app!</p>

    <br>
    <InertiaLink :href="$route('test')">Test</InertiaLink>
</template>

<script>
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

export default {
    components: {
        Head,
    },
}

</script>
```

Screen my error page[image]

I will be grateful for help

Comment: just use route('route_name') without $

Comment: you are trying to pass routes to the component that doesn't resolve

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Laravel with the Ziggy library, you have a global route() function helper available for you automatically.

Using Ziggy with Vue/Inertia, it's helpful to make this function available as a custom $route property so you can use it directly in your templates.

Option 1:

```
app.config.globalProperties.$route = route
```

Option 2:

```
createApp(App)
   .use({
          install(app) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
          app.config.globalProperties.$route = route;
        },
   })
```

Use:

```
<a href="$route('users.create')">Create User</a>
```

Comment: Maybe credit the docs next time? https://inertiajs.com/routing#generating-ur-ls

Answer (score 0):

In app.js-

```
import route from 'ziggy'
import { ZiggyVue } from './ziggy'

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin) // Change this
            .mixin({ methods: { route } }) // Add this
            .mount(el)
    },
})
```

Comment: sorry, but this not work for my case, i have the same error

Comment: @Pingo, sorry, can you see the edited answer and try?

Comment: @Zhrey, i try and i have new error - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ziggy' in /my/app.js

Comment: After you ran php artisan ziggy:generate, was  ./resources/js/ziggy.js there?

Comment: in first time i not run this command, but i try it, build is success. And i have next errors in browser console: `Uncaught TypeError: ziggy__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default() is not a function`, `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.$route is not a function`

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/tighten/ziggy/issues/238

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239263/vue3-app-initialization-chaining-syntax-with-config-globalproperties